# Grails CSV Plugin, CSVWriter Example not working

Tags: plugins, grails, csv, groovy

I'm working on a Grails project and I want to write some data from different domain objects to a csv. I thought I would just be able to use the CSV Plugin available. I downloaded and installed the Grails CSV plugin v.3 and to get it working I just thought I would try the example. Unfortunately, the example isn't working and I'm not sure why. I've posted the example below.

```
def sw = new StringWriter()
def b = new CSVWriter(sw) {
  col1 { it.val1 }
  col2 { it.val2 }
}
b << [val1: 'a', val2: 'b']
b << [val1: 'c', val2: 'd']
assert b.writer.toString() == '''"col1","col2"
"a","b"
"c","d"'''
```

It is throwing a compiler error saying unexpected token at col1. Am I doing something wrong here?

I was looking at the export plugin as well, but it doesn't seem as though I'm able to use data from multiple domain classes with that.

Comment: Can you add the actual exception to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your code to:

```
def sw = new StringWriter()
def b = new CSVWriter(sw, {
  col1 { it.val1 }
  col2 { it.val2 }
})
```

Generally, when the last argument is a closure, you can specify it outside parentheses, but it works only in top-level expressions -- in this example the top-level expression is an assignment.